# Angular2 Directive not reading given value

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I need a directive which will bind a dynamic value to an element's `classList`

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[entityType]"
})
export class EntityTypeDirective {
  @Input() entityType: string;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) { 
    var labelClass = {
      C: "label-warning",
      F: "label-info",
      S: "label-success"
    };
    el.nativeElement.classList = `label ${labelClass[this.entityType]}`;
  }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<span [entityType]="item.type">...<span>
```

**Problem**

The directive binds `class="label undefined"` because `entityType` is `undefined`. `item.type` is a value coming from an `*ngFor` repeater which I want to pass to the directive.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have gone wrong at the point where you should use the `ngOnInit` [**lifecycle hook**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#other-lifecycle-hooks) :). This is where the `@Input` binding is completed in angular

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[entityType]"
})
export class EntityTypeDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() entityType: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let labelClass: any = {
      C: "label-warning",
      F: "label-info",
      S: "label-success"
    };
    this.el.nativeElement.classList = `label ${labelClass[this.entityType]}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Input bindings are not available in the constructor, use `ngOnInit` instead.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html